# Add "more..." link in Tag Info box on Tagged Questions page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki, information-display, tags

When there is a lot of verbage in a Tag Wiki, only the first four lines show in the Tag Info box on the Tagged Questions page.

How about we add a **"more..."** link at the end to let people know that there is more to read?
It would have the same destination as the "about the xxx tag".

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change that split up tag wikis to excerpt posts and wiki posts took care of this.

We no longer truncate stuff mid sentence in the page.